# Adding external electric field in ORCA with specific strength

Tags: orca, electric-field

Can anybody share methods to apply an external Electric field in ORCA? thanks!

Comment: Hi! You could check this out https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jcc.26072.

Answer (score 7):

From the [ORCA forum](https://orcaforum.kofo.mpg.de) [thread](https://orcaforum.kofo.mpg.de/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=4461&p=18293&hilit=how%20to%20add%20electric%20field#p18293):

> Actually there is an undocumented feature for this purpose:

```
%scf
   efield X-field-strength-in-a.u. , Y-field-strength-in-a.u. , Z-field-strength-in-a.u.
end
```

> I have used it to compare dipole moments obtained via numeric and analytic differentiation and it worked fine. But do be careful as undocumented features do not officially exist (although in this case it might have just been overlooked in the manual)

I searched the [manual](https://orcaforum.kofo.mpg.de/app.php/dlext/?cat=1), but didn't find any mention about how to add it.